# Vehicle Loan Calculator

Tags: vb.net, finance

> A loan calculator has to be created for the proNetBank. Method of
>   processing the loan is as follows:
>
> Vehicle loan is given for a period of three to seven years depending
>   on the customers preference. the current interest rate is 20% per
>   annum. The minimum loan amount is lkr 500,000 and the maximum loan
>   amount is 7,000,000 , in addition maximum that could be obtained also
>   depends on the category of the vehicle as below.
>
> - Brand new or unregistered vehicles. Up to 100% of the vehicle value -vehicles within 6 years of 1st registration. Up to 85% of vehicle value hybrid brand new and unregistered vehicles within 2 years of
>     manufacturing. Up to 85% of the vehicle value.The application should
>     obtain the necessary inputs using appropriate controls and calculate
>     and display the installment value.

So I wrote my code:

```
Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbVeh5yrs.CheckedChanged
    If rbVeh5yrs.Checked = True Then
        txtBorrow.Visible = True
        lblBorrowingAmount.Text = "Enter the amount you want to borrow"
    Else
        txtBorrow.Visible = False
        lblBorrowingAmount.Text = ""
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    If txtBorrow.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Pls Enter the amount you want to borrow")
    Else
        intBorrow = txtBorrow.Text
        If intBorrow < 500000 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Lowest Amount which can be borrow is RS.500000")
        ElseIf intBorrow > 7000000 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Maximum amount which can be borrowed is RS.7000000")
        End If
    End If


    intBorrow = txtBorrow.Text
    If rbVeh5yrs.Checked = True Then
        decVehicle = intBorrow * 0.8
        decInterestPay = (decVehicle + (decVehicle * 0.2 * decYear))
        decInstallment = decInterestPay / decMonthly
        lblMonthlyPayment.Text = "Monthly Installments " & decInstallment
    End If


    If rbBN.Checked = True Then
        decVehicle = intBorrow
        decInterestPay = (decVehicle + (decVehicle * 0.2 * decYear))
        decInstallment = decInterestPay / decMonthly
        lblMonthlyPayment.Text = "Monthly Installments " & decInstallment

    End If

    If rbHybrid.Checked = True Then
        decVehicle = intBorrow * 0.8
        decInterestPay = (decVehicle + (decVehicle * 0.2 * decYear))
        decInstallment = decInterestPay / decMonthly
        lblMonthlyPayment.Text = "Monthly Installments " & decInstallment
    End If



End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbBN.CheckedChanged
    If rbBN.Checked = True Then
        txtBorrow.Visible = True
        lblBorrowingAmount.Text = " Enter the amount you want to borrow "
    Else

        txtBorrow.Visible = False
        lblBorrowingAmount.Text = ""

    End If




End Sub

Private Sub rbHybrid_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbHybrid.CheckedChanged
    If rbHybrid.Checked = True Then
        txtBorrow.Visible = True
        lblBorrowingAmount.Text = "Enter the amount you want to borrow"
    Else
        txtBorrow.Visible = False
        lblBorrowingAmount.Text = ""

    End If


End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub rb3Years_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rb3Years.CheckedChanged
    If rb3Years.Checked = True Then
        decYear = 3
        decMonthly = 36
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rb4Years_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rb4Years.CheckedChanged
    If rb4Years.Checked = True Then
        decYear = 4
        decMonthly = 36
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rb5Years_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rb5Years.CheckedChanged
    If rb5Years.Checked = True Then
        decYear = 5
        decMonthly = 48
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rb6Years_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rb6Years.CheckedChanged
    If rb6Years.Checked = True Then
        decYear = 6
        decMonthly = 60
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rb7Years_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rb7Years.CheckedChanged
    If rb7Years.Checked = True Then
        decYear = 7
        decMonthly = 72
    End If
End Sub
```

Can you check it and tell me whether it is good enough? If there is room for improvement, please let me know.

Comment: Is this a very simplified way to calculate interest that you are told to use? That's not how interest rates works in real situations. Is this an assignment? If so, are you seriously encouraged to use hungarian notation?

Comment: @guffa yes this is an assignment and i was given a fixed interest rate of 20% so what I have done is right?

Comment: @guffa yes thats what our teacher expects from us

Comment: Fire the teacher. Burn the Hungarian notation.

Comment: awh thnx man, just will pass the assignments with these, but wont use them once i start working, is my code correct? does it need any amendments? i mean have i declared the variables right???

Comment: Yes, if you were specifically told to just calculate the interest that way, it's correct. Normally the interest is calculated each month on the current amount owed, i.e. `amountOwed = amountOwed * (1 + 0.20 / 12) - monthlyPayment`. You haven't shown the declaration of any of the variables in the code, so it's impossible to tell if they are correct.

Comment: @guffa I dont understand what u imply. can u write the edited code for me with the equation? ill try and understand it then?

Comment: @guffa why am i wrong again?

Comment: @guffa you mean compound interest????

Comment: @Shihaan: The calculation that you have doesn't take the compound interest into account, but it also doesn't take the payments into account. You keep paying interest on the initial amount although you don't owe that much once you have started to make payments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to focus my review on just one Sub.

### btnCalculate_Click

- First off, I understand that your teacher wants you to use Hungarian
  notation, but out in the real world, this makes us cringe. Don't use
  it outside of class, [unless you plan on doing it
  right](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).
- You have a typo right here. Use "Please" instead of "Pls".

  > ```
  > MessageBox.Show("Pls Enter the amount you want to borrow")
  > ```
- And a potential bug soon after.

  > ```
  > intBorrow = txtBorrow.Text
  > ```

  You can't rely on a user to type in an Integer. You should use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) here instead. For example:

  ```
  If Int32.TryParse(txtBorrow.Text, intBorrow) Then
      ' current logic
  Else
      MessageBox.Show("You must enter an integer value to borrow.")
      Exit Sub
  End If
  ```
- You have more typos. The two strings you're showing to the user should be consistent.

  ```
  If intBorrow < 500000 Then
      MessageBox.Show("Lowest Amount which can be borrow is RS.500000")
  ElseIf intBorrow > 7000000 Then
      MessageBox.Show("Maximum amount which can be borrowed is RS.7000000")
  End If
  ```

  Also, consider what happens if the lowest amount and/or highest amount need to change. You would have to change it in two places. It's better to extract some constants so you only have to change it once. You should also look up [String.Format](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_strings.htm).

  ```
  Const lowestAmount As Integer = 50000
  Const highestAmount As Integer = 7000000
  Dim message As String = "{0} amount which can be borrowed is RS.{1}"

  If intBorrow < lowestAmount Then
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format(message,"Lowest",lowestAmount))
  ElseIf intBorrow > hightestAmount Then
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format(message,"Highest",HighestAmount))
  End If
  ```

  Lastly, I recommend extracting *all* of that logic into it's own subroutine in order to de-clutter the Click handler.
- I had to look ***really*** hard to find the difference between the next three `If` statements.  It turns out that the only thing that changes is what you set `decVechicle` to. Given that, don't repeat yourself. The rest of that code gets executed no matter what, so remove it from the inside of the If block.

  ```
  If rbVeh5yrs.Checked OrElse rbHybrid.Checked Then
      decVehicle = intBorrow * 0.8
  Else rbBN.Checked Then
      decVehicle = intBorrow
  End If

  decInterestPay = (decVehicle + (decVechicle * 0.2 * decYear))
  '.... etc
  ```

  I also want you to take note of two things.

  1. There's no need to say `If rbVeh5yrs.Checked = True`. When you do that, what you're really saying is `If True = True` (or alternatively, `If False = True`).
  2. You also take the same action whether `rbVeh5yrs` or `rbHybrid` is `Checked`. So, I used the [OrElse Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx). We could also switch the order up a little bit and check `rbBN.Checked` first, and then catch the others in the `Else` part of the `If` block.

     ```
     If rbBN.Checked Then
         decVehicle = intBorrow
     Else
         decVechicle = intBorrow * 0.8
     End If

     decInterestPay = (decVehicle + (decVechicle * 0.2 * decYear))
     '.... etc
     ```

Comment: would it be easier if i did these using a function? I still feel this could be done better

Comment: Yes! By all means yes! Extract functions! Normally I would scold you for having the logic so tightly bound to your form, but I figured you're taking classes and haven't been doing this long so I took it easy on you. ++ for nice formatting though. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: thanks man . thank you very much, can you show  me an example of how i could use a function to do one part? if you show me one i'll do the rest and post you the code only if you can

Comment: what does this mean? "Dim message As String = "{0} amount which can be borrowed is RS.{1}"" I have not learnt that

Comment: `{0}` and `{1}` stand in for the arguments that you pass into `String.Format()`. I left a link in my answer that will take you to some examples.